# int To String Representation of Fixed Length

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I have a function that accepts a few integer params, and needs to convert then to ASCII string representation of a fixed length of 4. i.e. 4 becomes "0004" and 42 becomes "0042". It is safe to assume the params will be 0<=n<=9999

I could do that with something like:

```
void foo(int a, int b) {
    std::string sa = std::to_string(a);
    std::string sb = std::to_string(b);

    for(int i = sa.length; i < 4; i++)
        sa.insert(0,"0");
    ...
}
```

But that seems like more than I should need, especially if there are a lot of params to convert. is there a more efficient way to do this?

**Edit:** the goal is not to print the resulting strings.

**Edit 2:** something based around  `ss << std::setw( 4 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) << number;` does what I need, thank you for the comments.

Comment: A string stream with `setw` works fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean? I'm new to c++ and not particularly familiar with streams.

Comment: This is called "zero-padding". Now you may go research.

Comment: @lkrasner, Look through some of the examples of [`iomanip`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::ostringstream` and treat it like an output stream:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << std::setw( 4 ) << std::setfill( '0' ) << number;
Send_To_Serial(ss.str().c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think snprintf is a good candidate:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char buffer[5];
    // Prints: 0001
    snprintf(buffer, 5, "%04d", 1);
    std::cout << buffer << '\n';
    // Prints: 1234 (not the 5)
    snprintf(buffer, 5, "%04d", 12345);
    std::cout << buffer << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the goal is not to print the resulting strings. they will actually eventually be sent over serial to a sensor.

Comment: @lkrasner Just omit cout and send the 4 bytes of the buffer